# Making sure data is loaded

Tags: google-bigquery

I use the following command to load data.

```
/home/bigquery/bq load --max_bad_record=30000 -F '^'  company.junelog entry.gz country:STRING,telco_name:STRING,datetime:STRING, ...
```

It has happened that when I got non-zero return code the data was still loaded. How do I make sure that the command is successful or not? Checking return code does not seem to help. There are times when I loaded the same file again because I got an error but the data was already available in bigquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bq show -j  of the load job and check job status.
If you are writing code to do the load, so you don't know the job id, you can pass the job id into the load operation (as long as it is unique) so you will know which job to check.

For instance you can run

`/home/bigquery/bq load --job_id=some_unique_job_id --max_bad_record=30000 -F '^'  company.junelog entry.gz country:STRING,telco_name:STRING,datetime:STRING, ...'`

then
`/home/bigquery/bq show --j some_unique_job_id`

Note if you are creating new tables for every load (as opposed to appending), you could use the write disposition WRITE_EMPTY to make sure you only did the load if the table was empty, thus preventing adding the same data twice. This isn't directly supported in bq.py, but you could use the underlying bigquery_client.py to make this call, or use the REST api directly.

Comment: # FATAL Flags parsing error: Unknown command line flag 'job_id' # Run 'bq help' to get help ## /home/bigquery/bq version
## This is BigQuery CLI v2.0.4